# Svelte dev on https - don't detect changes

Tags: https, svelte, rollupjs

I'm running Svelte dev on https locally.

First - generated the key.pem and cert.pem with `openssl` command (used the example in `sirv-cli` page in npm). Then - I set these commands in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "HOST=0.0.0.0 sirv public --no-clear --port 443 --http2 --cert cert.pem --key key.pem"
  },
```

And so - I'm able to open my project on https. In my case - on `https://example.com`.

(I need to use https because our APIs will reject the requests if I don't use https.)

The problem is that now when I make a change in some file in `src/` - nothing changes in the browser. I have to do a refresh in the browser and only then I'll see the new code.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or something I need to add maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with using svelte-webpack template - https://github.com/sveltejs/template-webpack. When I run this with https - then the changes of files reflect in the browser.

(For setting Webpack to work with HTTPS I used this tutorial - https://bleext.com/post/how-to-enable-https-on-webpack-dev-server - and for the certificate files - cert and key - I used the two `.pem` files from my initial post above.)